# Trying to boot Surface 4 Pro to WINPE - USB

Tags: boot, uefi, microsoft-surface, winpe

I've been trying to boot up to WINPE on 2 different Windows 10 tablets from an external USB hard drive. The tablets won't boot from USB. Strange enough, the same external hard drive with the same WinPE boots just fine on a normal Windows 8-10 Dell laptop.

I am assuming it has something to do with the tablet's UEFI but can't figure out what is wrong - any help is appreciated.

Please note that my external hard drive is formatted with FAT32 under 32GB and I have the same issue on 2 out of the box tablet.

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot?

Answer (score 0):

With the Surface Pro powered off, try holding Volume Down and press the power button.

> **[Boot Surface from a USB device | Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023511/surface-boot-surface-from-a-usb-device)**
>
> **Surface Pro 1796, Surface Pro LTE, Surface Laptop, Surface Book 2, Surface Studio, Surface Book, Surface Pro 4, Surface 3, or Surface Pro
>   3 with a configured boot order in UEFI**
>
> 1. Shut down your Surface.
> 2. Insert the bootable USB drive into the USB port on your Surface.
> 3. Press the power button to turn it on.
> 4. Follow the on-screen instructions to boot from your USB drive.
>
> **Surface Pro 1796, Surface Pro LTE, Surface Laptop, Surface Book 2, Surface Studio, Surface Book, Surface Pro without a configured boot
>   order in UEFI**
>
> 1. Shut down your Surface.
> 2. Insert the bootable USB drive into the USB port on your Surface.
> 3. Press and hold the volume-down button on Surface.
> 4. While holding down the volume-down button, press and release the power button.
> 5. The Microsoft or Surface logo appears on your screen. Continue to hold the volume-down button. Release the button once spinning dots
>      appear beneath the logo.
> 6. Follow the on-screen instructions to boot from your USB drive.

Comment: I already follow that - still not working